# What does .do webpage stands for

Tags: file-extension

I would like to know what does `.do` webpages stand for ( as `.php` stands for PHP pages with PHP Scripting) and what is the scripting language behind it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/do

According to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do), `.do` is:

> a pseudo file extension representing
>   an Apache Struts action. It does not
>   map to an actual file extension,
>   although it appears that way.

However, you can't really say anything about the technology behind based solely on the "extension", i.e., the server can be configured to use `.do` for PHP files etc. This can be done in order to secure backwards compatibility or [whatever](http://filext.com/faq/fake_file_extensions.php).

Comment: I've also seen quite a few Spring MVC applications which have `.do` pages which really are just `.jsp`:s under the shroud.

Answer (score 7):

**.do** is the commonly used convention to denote a Struts action. Like **.jsf** for JSF .
But there is no compulsion that all struts action should map to **.do** extenstion. It can be configured in 
web.xml to **.anything**. Also a simple servlet can also be mapped to a **.do** extension. So nothing can be derived by just looking
at the URL.

Answer (score 3):

While `.do` seems to be a Struts convention, it is used in Spring and Spring MVC as well.  This SO thread talks a little bit about that, also noting that whereever Servlets are used, '.do' files can be used: [Why do Java webapps use .do extension? Where did it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597582/why-do-java-webapps-use-do-extension-where-did-it-come-from)