# Why do Java webapps use .do extension? Where did it come from?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have always wondered why so many Java developers use ".do" as the extension for their web controller (MVC) resources. Example: http://example.com/register.do

It doesn't even seem to be framework specific as I have seen it in Spring MVC and Struts projects.
Where did this ".do" extension practice come from. Why was this done instead of no extension?
I feel like I missed the Java world memo on this.

Personally I prefer no extension.

Comment: Friendly note for people that want to migrate from ".do" and have friendly URLS.
Use the servlet path instead of the extension ie /do/login and then use Tuckey Filter URL rewritting to make /do/login ==> /login.

Comment: True, URL rewriting (be it through mod_rewrite or Tuckey's filter) would do the trick.

Comment: it's pretty idiotic, and there is no excuse for that.

Comment: For `.action` in Struts2: [What does .action / .event at an end of a url mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27780210)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To my knowledge, this convention has been spread by Struts1. The user guide puts it like this:

> #### [5.4.2 Configure the ActionServlet Mapping](http://read.pudn.com/downloads50/ebook/169473/The%20Struts%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf)
>
> **Note:**  The material in this section is not specific to Struts. The
>   configuration of servlet mappings is
>   defined in the Java Servlet
>   Specification. This section describes
>   the most common means of configuring a
>   application.
>
> There are two common approaches to
>   defining the URLs that will be
>   processed by the controller servlet --
>   prefix matching and extension
>   matching. An appropriate mapping entry
>   for each approach will be described
>   below.
>
> Prefix matching means that you want
>   all URLs that start (after the context
>   path part) with a particular value to
>   be passed to this servlet. Such an
>   entry might look like this:
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/do/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> which means that a request URI to
>   match the `/logon` path described
>   earlier might look like this:
>
> ```
> http://www.mycompany.com/myapplication/do/logon
> ```
>
> where `/myapplication` is the context
>   path under which your application is
>   deployed.
>
> Extension mapping, on the other hand,
>   matches request URIs to the action
>   servlet based on the fact that the URI
>   ends with a period followed by a
>   defined set of characters. For
>   example, the JSP processing servlet is
>   mapped to the `*.jsp` pattern so that
>   it is called to process every JSP page
>   that is requested. **To use the `*.do`
>   extension (which implies "do
>   something")**, the mapping entry would
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> and a request URI to match the
>   `/logon` path described earlier might
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> http://www.mycompany.com/myapplication/logon.do
> ```
>
> **WARNING** - The framework will not operate correctly if you define more
>   than one `<servlet-mapping>` element
>   for the controller servlet.
>
> **WARNING** - If you are using the new module support since version 1.1, you
>   should be aware that only extension
>   mapping is supported.

And I think this convention has been kept (sometimes [to not change URLs](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) even after replacing Struts1, sometimes just because people were happy with it).

Comment: I figured it was Struts 1. Such a long time ago I must have forgotten. Those were the not so good days for Java Web Dev.

Comment: @Adam At that time (~2001), I was happy with Struts1. Today, using it would make me cry.

Comment: In 2001 we were LUCKY to have Struts 1!

Comment: With Struts 2 we can all be happy!

Answer (score 11):

It was common practice to map your struts servlet to *.do in web.xml to pass URLs to the struts servlet.  For example:

```
<!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

There is really no reason except convention for this.  If you use no extension you need to do some magic to handle images and other static content in a way that doesn't send them to your sevlet.  Often this gets done at a load balancer of a fronting web server.

Comment: I don't know about it being magic. All it is having a master dispatching servlet and maybe doing some URL rewriting to avoid having the /myservlet/ prefix. See Tuckey URL rewritting.