# Using .do extension in jsp

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

When do we use .do in JSP code. For example, 
How does the below code works

```
<a href="myUsedVouchers.do" >Used Vouchers</a>
```

Comment: there is a good answer to this in the following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597582/why-do-java-webapps-use-do-extension-where-did-it-come-from

Answer (score 5):

`.do` is the general extension of actions using [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2):

.do is used for action forward mapping.

`<action input="/" name="MyForm" path="/myFormHandler" scope="request" type="com.app.actions.MyFormHandler" validate="false">
            <forward name="myform" path="/MyForm.do"/>
        </action>`

Comment: As I am using springs, does the below code act as the action.              @RequestMapping(value = "/myVouchers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView getMyVouchers(HttpSession session) throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
  String userName = UserSession.getUserNameFromSession();
  return getMerchantVoucherCount(userName, null, session);
 }

Comment: I've not used spring. But, [this might be useful for you](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/) & [this one also](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-code-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is a struts extension , which is mapped in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/do/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```