# What does .action / .event at an end of a url mean?

Tags: url

"https://www.evernote.com/Home.action"

Hi I was browsing Evernote and Mint.com and noticed that they both have .event / .action at the end of the url like above. What is the significance of it? How do you add something like that to an end of a url?

Comment: For `.do` in Struts1: [Why do Java webapps use .do extension? Where did it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3597582)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that the website is based on Struts2 framework by apache. Struts2 is a popular Java framework for creating Enterprise level java applications. All struts2 based sites have that ".action" ending URL.

This can be changed from the config file.

Source: http://struts.apache.org/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html

Changing configuration: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_configuration.htm

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer! Never knew such a framework existed.