# Load dynamic .jsp page on pageload with specific servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pageload

I would like to create a .jsp page that is to be loaded on pageload, but the content of the page is dynamically created by calling my local database.

My question is. When a user request the index.jsp page, how do i "say".
Before displaying the index.jsp page call servletX to get content, and send this **back** to the index.jsp page?

I have mapping my jsp and servlet together as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ServletBooks</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But dont know how i send the dispather, back to self?
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(***???***).forward(request, response);

Edit.
Okey so now the site works as follows.
I request the index.jsp page, which is mapped in the web.xml to a servlet.
But if i set the requestDispatcher to the index.jsp page, the whole site hangs. If i set it to another page like result1.jsp it works fine. Execpt it isint the index page displaying the content.

How do i say to the servlet, send output to initiator?

Comment: Rather than going from jsp -> servlet, i would map a servlet to that jsp's path, and use the servlet to include your jsp.

Comment: Do you have any example of how to do so and the result?

Comment: Try something like this https://zack6849.com/uploads/N2VmYjA3Y2Y0.png 
 and this https://zack6849.com/uploads/ZTZjMzlhNGU0.png

Comment: Im not sure i follow, you ALWAYS need to call a index page before anything else can be called? And how do you in a servlet say "send the output back to initiator" instead of calling a new page like a result.jsp page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if i set the requestDispatcher to the index.jsp page, the whole
>   site hangs. If i set it to another page like result1.jsp it works
>   fine.

Yes, because it is obviously going into an infinite loop as index.jsp is mapped to the Servlet you are forwarding from.

You need to have a look at the ModelViewController pattern. Essentially you **never** allow direct access to JSP but route through a controller, in your case a simple Servlet which will load any data required for the view and then dispatch to the view for rendering.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ServletBooks</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loadBooks.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- If you are on Tomcat set a Default page if root of webapp requested -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loadBooks.do</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In your servlet load the data and now forward to index.jsp.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: So the /loadBooks.do is a servlet?
Why does it have a [dot]do?

Comment: You can make it whatever you want but why .do? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597582/why-do-java-webapps-use-do-extension-where-did-it-come-from

Comment: Im no JSP pro and i dont quite get it yet. What does loadBooks.do represent. Is it a servlet that passes the request and response objects to another servlet that then creates that page? Is it a fiction value that does not exist as a physical file? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for all the info i got it working following the example, after realising the url-pattern is just a fictitious value that act as a link between two things.