# .do extension in web pages?

Tags: execution

I want to know what is .do extension in web pages. Is it a standard extension, or, if it's not, can we change the extension (like `client-login.php` to `client-login.do` and still run as PHP)?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which programming language has extension .do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973505/which-programming-language-has-extension-do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does .do webpage stands for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117694/what-does-do-webpage-stands-for)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is whatever it is configured to be on that particular web server.  A web server could be configured to run .pl files with the php module and .aspx files with perl, although that would be silly.  There are no scripts involved with most web servers, instead you'd have to look in your apache configuration files (or equivalent, if using different server software).  If you have permission to edit the server config file, then you could make files ending in .do run as php, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Yeah - in the end, a web server is just a program, and it can do whatever it feels like to come up with its content. It doesn't have to mirror the filesystem, though your standard basic web server setup does work on that model because it's awfully convenient. A good application will more often than not have some measure of abstraction between the URL and the actual actions, too.

Comment: While this answer is true, I think the real question is what technology are they most likely using. Which is answered by MK below. It looks like they are probably using Java and the Structs framework.

Comment: @luisperezphd: It looks to me like Vishwanath wanted to hide what language he is using, and he saw that some other websites use `.do`, and wanted to know if he could similarly obfuscate his filenames.  The question is tagged `php` after all.

Answer (score 170):

.do comes from the Struts framework.  See this question:
[Why do Java webapps use .do extension? Where did it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597582/why-do-java-webapps-use-do-extension-where-did-it-come-from)
Also you can change what your urls look like using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (on Apache).

Answer (score 47):

".do" is the "standard" extension mapped to for Struts Java platform. See http://struts.apache.org/ .

Answer (score 3):

Using apache's rewrite_module can change your script extensions.  Give this [thread](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread84152.html) a good read.

Comment: any example for better understanding ?