# Which programming language has extension .do

Tags: file-extension

Just wondering which programming languages is used on the web pages with the extension ".do"

Comment: @Kobi that simple search led me to this page ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does .do webpage stands for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117694/what-does-do-webpage-stands-for)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

According to [FileInfo](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/do), the file extension is for [Java Servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet).

Answer (score 39):

Strictly speaking, you can't tell for sure just by looking at the extension. I can configure a web server to interpret `*.do` URLs as referring to PHP files or even executables and run it accordingly. In fact, `*.do` URLs may not even refer to files at all! It really does depend on how the server is configured.

Comment: @Kobi Actually that's just a url re-write where they add text from the question (“which-programming-language-has-extension-do”) after the question id (`5973505`). You'll notice it redirects to the full url

Comment: While true, this answer is more pedantic than useful. As Femi points out, in practice, this extension does indicate a particular web stack.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Sure. That's why I said "strictly speaking". And even if it is pedantic, it is *correct*. IMO correctness is just as important as knowing what is usually done in practice.

Comment: Like Kirk said, this answer is pedantic. Sure, you ***can*** change how various extensions are handled, but the OP was asking which languages use `.do` extensions, implying the OP wanted to know which languages use `.do` files by default. If someone asked what languages use `.php` files, the practical answer is PHP. Yes, you ***could*** configure your server to execute `.php` files as Perl or something unrelated like that, but by default, in general, and most often in practice, `.php` refers to PHP files. That same basic principle can be applied here.

Comment: This is a 100% universal truth about file extensions in general.  I fail to see how it in any way relates to this specific file extension.  Perhaps it's useful to note this extension resides only inside web-servers and this answer does mention web-servers.  That's the only possible relevance I can find.

Comment: This belongs as an addendum to a proper answer, not as an answer by itself. It imparts no useful information to someone looking for guidance, no matter how correct it might be.

Answer (score 26):

That is typically not so much a programming language feature but a framework feature: apps developed with Apache Struts (see http://struts.apache.org/) typically use that extension.

Answer (score 8):

.do extension is used to build a J2EE enterprise application using Struts and dao factory method that is latest technology framework to build EE applications. It is much faster and efficient than JSP and JSF.